# How do I send a message to the user when their email does not match typed input email?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an email typed into field in my html file. I also have the user email captured by the Code.gs file.

I have figured out how to check to make sure these two match. However, I cannot figure out how to make a pop-up message (alert of any kind) appear on the user's screen when these do or do not match. (EX: 'user email does not match typed email' when failed and 'successful match' when it match)

```
if(userEmail == typedEmail){
  Logger.log('Success!');
}
else{
  Logger.log('Fail!');
}
```

I would like to add a message before `Logger.log('Success!');` and `Logger.log('Fail!');`

The `Logger.log` is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

#### Requirement:

Send an alert to the spreadsheet user if email addresses don't match.

---

#### Solution:

Since I don't have the rest of your function I can't format the code too well, but this section should look something like this to achieve your goal:

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
if(userEmail == typedEmail){
  ui.alert('Successful match');
  Logger.log('Success!');
} 
else{
  ui.alert('User email does not match with typed email');
  Logger.log('Fail!');
}
```

---

#### Explanation:

We can use `ui.alert()` to send an alert to the user of the spreadsheet, all you need to do is define the message inside your brackets. I copied the ones from your question as an example.

---

#### References:

1. [Class `Ui` Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)

Comment: When I've tried SpreadsheetApp.getUi() as you've suggested, it says I cannot call the SpreadsheetApp function (I'm not sure if function is the correct terminology, sorry. I'm pretty new to this.) Anyways, this part of the code is in a validation function I created, it is not in the doGet() function. I'm not sure if this is the reason. It is on the Code.gs file. I'm thinking I somehow need to create a toast message or something by calling the HTML to do so somehow. I'm pretty lost though, if I can make an alert pop up in my Code.gs validation function, not doGet, that would definitely suffice!

Comment: Also, I'm sorry I didn't post all of the code. This code is for an HTML with some inputs from the user on the HTML side. There is a spreadsheet that the responses are logged, but the input is not typed in a spreadsheet itself. Does that make a difference? Do I still use SpreadsheetApp? I don't understand enough to know what SprradsheetApp exactly means honestly. I assumed FormApp meant Google form, DocumentApp meant Google docs, etc, but I could be wrong in my assumption I really am pretty darn new to coding (about 2 weeks in.)

Comment: I did try to use the suggestion, thank you for it! This is the error I got on my Console:  Uncaught  at userClicked (Code:32) (VHP) e10a278c-7290-4d71-b55b-cc88bdaa598d, it also gave me a link. My userClicked Code 32 line is: var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

Comment: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. (line 25, file "Code") is what I get now. I moved the SpreadhseetApp.getUi() to line 25 from 32. But what can my code not call the SpreadsheetApp?

Comment: The fact that this is a HTML form that inputs data into a sheet rather than a standalone sheet changes this completely - this solution will not work.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry I didn't clarify this. Thanks for your solution!